# Divide hours interval in minutes with Luxon

Tags: luxon

How can I divide an hours interval in minutes with Luxon? Example

```
starTime = 06:00
endaTime = 12:00
interval = 00:30

["06:00AM", "06:30AM", "07:00AM", "07:30AM", "08:00AM", "08:30AM", "09:00AM", "09:30AM", "10:00AM", "10:30AM", "11:00AM", "11:30AM"]
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can simply:

- Create [`DateTime`](https://moment.github.io/luxon/docs/class/src/datetime.js%7EDateTime.html) object for start and end time using [`DateTime.fromFormat`](https://moment.github.io/luxon/docs/class/src/datetime.js%7EDateTime.html#static-method-fromFormat)
- Create [`Duration`](https://moment.github.io/luxon/docs/class/src/duration.js%7EDuration.html) object for your *"interval"* using [`Duration.fromISOTime`](https://moment.github.io/luxon/docs/class/src/duration.js%7EDuration.html#static-method-fromISOTime)
- Loop until you reach end time, adding interval at each interation (see [Comparing DateTimes](https://moment.github.io/luxon/docs/manual/math.html#comparing-datetimes) and [`plus`](https://moment.github.io/luxon/docs/class/src/datetime.js%7EDateTime.html#instance-method-plus))

Example:

```js
const DateTime = luxon.DateTime;
const Duration = luxon.Duration;
const startTime = "06:00"
const endTime = "12:00"
const interval = "00:30"

const dtStart = DateTime.fromFormat(startTime, "HH:mm");
const dtEnd = DateTime.fromFormat(endTime, "HH:mm");
const durationInterval = Duration.fromISOTime(interval);

let res = [];
let i = DateTime.fromFormat(startTime, "HH:mm");
while (i < dtEnd) {
  res.push(i.toFormat("HH:mma"));
  i = i.plus(durationInterval);
}
console.log(res);
```

```html
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/luxon@1.26.0/build/global/luxon.js"></script>
```

Comment: Considering the fact that DateTime is immutable, I don't understand why we need to create 'i' from the 'startTime', can't we use the 'dtStart' itself?

Comment: @SarathSMenon `dtStart` can be used as you suggested, but I've put `i` to have show clearly the loop part of the snippet and do not overwrite the value of `dtStart` (and transforming `const` in `let`). Feel free to customize the code according your needs in your codebase.

Answer (score 1):

```
import { Interval } from "luxon"

Interval
  .fromDateTimes(startTime, endTime)))
  .splitBy({minutes: 30})
```